# create help text for a field dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms

I have my response form and view like this

```
class ResponseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ResponseModel
        exclude = ('author', 'title','submit_count')
        # help_texts = {
        #     'ans1': user.q1.value,
        # }

@login_required
def ResponseFormView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            submission = form.save(commit=False)
            submission.author = request.user
            submission.save()
            return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})
    else:
        form = ResponseForm()
        return render(request, 'response_tem.html', {'form': form})
```

I want the help text for 'ans1' field to be the value of q1 field of `request.user`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class ResponseForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         user = kwargs.pop('user', None)  # popping user from known arguments
         super(ResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
         if user:
              self.fields['ans1'].help_text = "Help Text for {}".format(user.username)

    class Meta:
        model = ResponseModel
        exclude = ('author', 'title','submit_count')

@login_required
def ResponseFormView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            submission = form.save(commit=False)
            submission.author = request.user
            submission.save()
            return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})
    else:
        form = ResponseForm(user=request.user)  # passing user as known argument
        return render(request, 'response_tem.html', {'form': form})
```

Here, in the view I am passing the `request.user` as known argument when I am initiating Form Class's Object (marked with comment). Then in the Form, I am catching the `user` sent from view and updating the field's help text.